# Namespacing events in Javascript/AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, naming-conventions

I'm wondering if is there a naming convention to namespacing events with AngularJS?

[jQuery defines its convention](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) as `event.namespace` (with namespace at the **end**, and **dot** separator)

I've seen some articles ([example](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/)) where events are named like this: `namespace::event` (with namespace at the **start**; and **double-colon** separator)

Is there a common practice on this subject?

Thanks for your thoughts about it.

Comment: Yeah I've learned about jQuery event namespacing yesterday while looking for something else in the docs. I find the ``event.namespace`` notation a bit odd (I think the namespace should be written before the event it contains) and thus prefer using ``namespace:event`` or ``namespace::event`` for my Angular events though, I find it much clearer. But never saw any best practices about this, as long as you adopt one and only one convention accross your whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't heard of anything specific regarding angular, but you should consider that namespacing is a generally good practice for many situations. If you're writing a simple app that won't incorporate other scripts, there isn't much need to namespace. Just consider what *could* happen in the future of your script's environment (whether event's names could end up clashing) and base your decision on that.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, thanks for your answer.

I've no doubt about the benefits of namespacing and I'm already using it in all of my projects (web or not, with(out) Angular, etc). My questions was more around any convention to prefix these events to avoid conflicts with others libraries.

The first part of your answer brings more insights about it.

Comment: I just looked around too and didn't find advice to namespace events, which really surprised me. I don't fully agree with @m59 about whether there is need to namespace when not incorporating other scripts. It depends on how big your app is and how many events (and event types) there are. Just like global variables are fine for very small programs, but are bad for larger (i.e. most) programs.

Comment: @TylerCollier that's what I said.... "Just consider what *could* happen in the future". I namespace everything as much as possible in every project.